# Upload all release versions of tools with juju's local (lxc) provider?

Tags: juju

I'm using the local lxc provider on trusty, with the `default-series: trusty` option. Whenever I try to deploy a non-trusty charm, it never finishes (stays in pending state), and the log says

```
machine-0: 2014-06-22 00:28:59 ERROR juju runner.go:220 worker: exited "environ-provisioner": failed to process updated machines: cannot start machine 9: no matching tools available
```

How can I upload tools for all versions so I don't just have to use charms from the version I specified with `default-series`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this when you bootstrap juju. From the help page for that:

```
--series  (= )
    upload tools for supplied comma-separated series list
--upload-tools  (= false)
    upload local version of tools before bootstrapping
```

So if you do something like

```
juju bootstrap --upload-tools --series=precise,quantal,raring,saucy,trusty
```

it will upload the tools for those versions.